# Matlab: read time stamp in a loop

Tags: matlab, loops, csv

I need to read several hundred `.csv` data files, each of them with a fixed  number of columns and variable number of rows of type:

`'%s %d %d %d %u:%u %d %s %s %s %s'`

Which corresponds to:

`text1  2014  2  1 1:56 -2 text2  text3  text4  text5`

I need to correctly import the timestamp distinguishing minutes and hours and store them in 2 separate columns.

---

Part of my program:

```
directory_name = 'C:\Deutsche_Bank\';
filePattern = [directory_name, filesep, '*.csv'];
files = dir(directory_name);
fileIndex = find(~[files.isdir]);
fileIndex = fileIndex';

for df = 3:size(fileIndex, 1)+2; %start always from 3
    fileName = files(df).name;
    TempFullName = [directory_name, filesep, fileName];
    fmt = '%s %d %d %d %u:%u %d %s %s %s %s';
    fid = fopen('TempFullName');
    MyTimeStamp = textscan(fid, fmt, 'delimiter', ',');
    fclose(fid);

    ... more matlab for data analysis

end
```

Unfortunately with this program the output in `MyTimeStamp` is a set of empty cells, whereas if I specify directly the file:

```
fid = fopen('C:\Deutsche_Bank\myfile.csv');
```

I obtain a nice `MyTimeStamp` with the data correctly stored.

It seems it is the loop that is producing a problem, but I do not know what to do.

Comment: `fid = fopen(TempFullName)` --> Does this change help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `fid = fopen('TempFullName')` to `fid = fopen(TempFullName)`